# Is it possible to define an Object inside InputType? or can i define an InputType inside an InputType?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm, graphql-mutation

**A survey contains an array of question.
Is it possible to have an array of InputType or Question?**

```
@InputType()
export class SurveyInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  name: string
  @Field(() => String)
  status: string
  @Field(() => String)
  category: string
  @Field(() => String)
  initiativeId: string
  @Field(() => QuestionInput)
  questions: QuestionInput[]
}
@InputType()
export class QuestionInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  question: string
  @Field(() => String)
  maxPoint: number
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `String` instead of `string` type ?

Comment: Because its a Graphql Type. Anyway, this is not my problem because this works fine for me except that i would like to have an array input of question/InputQuestion. Thank you a lot for your efforts!

Comment: If you want to array of `QuestionInput ` please try Array<QuestionInput > or QuestionInput []

Answer (score 1):

**That's how i solved it at the end**

```
@InputType()
export class SurveyInput {

  @Field(() => String)
  name: string
  @Field(() => String)
  status: string
  @Field(() => String)
  category: string
  @Field(() => String)
  initiativeId: string

  @Field(() => [QuestionInput])
  questions: QuestionInput[]
}


@InputType()
export class QuestionInput {

  @Field(() => String)
  question: string

  @Field(() => Number)
  maxPoint: number
}
```